# How did the CryptoKitties contracts update, given that contracts are immutable?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

How did the CryptoKitties contracts update?

There were CryptoKitties [bounty programs](https://github.com/dapperlabs/cryptokitties-bounty) which suggests that the contracts changed over time in order to address issues.

How? I peeked at the sources for some of the contracts and couldn't see anything like the [OpenZeppelin proxy pattern](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies) for updating contracts.